# Cassandra - How can I compare timestamp?

Tags: date, cassandra, timestamp

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytablename (
  name text,
  typeid int,
  activefrom timestamp,
  status text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((name), typeid, activefrom)
)
```

I would like to query a range of timestamp activefrom, for example here some queries:

- activefrom > '2000-01-02'
- activefrom > '2000-01-02' AND activefrom < '2010-01-02'

I noticed that it doesn't work as in sql.

For example

```
 name | typeid | activefrom               | status
 ------+--------+--------------------------+--------------
  dani |  99999 | 1970-01-26 00:00:00+0000 | OK
  dani |  99999 | 1970-01-26 01:00:00+0000 | OK
  dani |  99999 | 2070-01-26 00:00:00+0000 | OK
  dani |  99999 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000 | OK
```

Query:

```
  select * from mytablename where name='dani' and typeid=99999 and activefrom > '2070-01-02 12:51:58+0000';
```

I have as result this:

```
  dani |  99999 | 2070-01-26 00:00:00+0000 | OK
  dani |  99999 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000 | OK
```

Cassandra version:

```
  cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.1.13.1218 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: can you show your exact query.

Comment: Yeah, of course, I just added it.

Comment: This sounds really weird.  Which version of Cassandra are you on?

Comment: cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.1.13.1218 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0

Comment: Here's a thought...try the following query: `SELECT name, typeid, activefrom, blobasbigint(timestampasblob(activefrom)) FROM mytablename WHERE name='dani' and typeid=99999 and activefrom > '2070-01-02 12:51:58+0000';`  I'm curious to see the UNIX timestamp that your 1970-01-01 timestamp translates to.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same and this is what I got.

```js
cqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE mytablename (
    ...   name text,
    ...   typeid int,
    ...   activefrom timestamp,
    ...   status text,
    ...   PRIMARY KEY ((name), typeid, activefrom)
    ... )
    ... ;

cqlsh:test> insert into mytablename (name,typeid,activefrom,status) values ('dani',99999,'1970-01-26 00:00:00+0000','OK');
cqlsh:test> insert into mytablename (name,typeid,activefrom,status) values ('dani',99999,'1970-01-26 01:00:00+0000','OK');
cqlsh:test> insert into mytablename (name,typeid,activefrom,status) values ('dani',99999,'2070-01-26 00:00:00+0000','OK');
cqlsh:test> insert into mytablename (name,typeid,activefrom,status) values ('dani',99999,'1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000','OK');
cqlsh:test> select * from mytablename;

 name | typeid | activefrom                      | status
------+--------+---------------------------------+--------
 dani |  99999 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000+0000 |     OK
 dani |  99999 | 1970-01-26 00:00:00.000000+0000 |     OK
 dani |  99999 | 1970-01-26 01:00:00.000000+0000 |     OK
 dani |  99999 | 2070-01-26 00:00:00.000000+0000 |     OK

(4 rows)
cqlsh:test>   select * from mytablename where name='dani' and typeid=99999 and activefrom > '2070-01-02 12:51:58+0000';

 name | typeid | activefrom                      | status
------+--------+---------------------------------+--------
 dani |  99999 | 2070-01-26 00:00:00.000000+0000 |     OK

(1 rows)
cqlsh:test>
```

version info : [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.4-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: So my problem is that when I insert new lines it is not inserting in correct order

Comment: insert order should not be an issue. I suspect Cassandra version. Can you try with a different version.

Comment: Yeah I tried with different version and It works fine. So it is the version of cassandra. unfortunately I could not change or upgrate it, so I resolved in Java. I retrieved all data and I compared after I parsed them. Not the best solution but it works. And also the data are not too much, like 10-20 max 50 for each query